# Best way to capture screen time for each individual component for our (React Native/Expo w/ Firebase) app?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, analytics, firebase-analytics

I am looking for a potential means of tracking my user's screen time on each individual component of our Expo mobile application and was wondering if someone could offer suggestions as to how I would do this with our Firebase backend?

To further elaborate, say I have a "notifications" screen and a "messages" screen--how would I track the user screen time on those screens? I wouldn't want a sum of those but a rather the individual length spent on each screen.

I have taken a look at the expo-firebase-analytics package (documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/) specifically, but due to Expo's universality, a lot of features are lost along the way.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to track each individual component in your Expo app by [logging a manual screen_view event](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/08/google-analytics-manual-screen-view.html) for whichever component / subscreen you want to track, and passing in the relevant `firebase_screen` and `firebase_screen_class` parameters.

Note that in order to get accurate time spent on screens in different sections, you'll need to change the `firebase_screen` parameter in a follow-up `screen_view` event to demarcate one screen from the other, and allow analytics to measure and collect the time between screens.